# Automatically Delete MongoDB Collection When User is Idle

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am sitting with one requirement for a couple of days, but not able to get a proper solution for this.
I have some login mechanism, upon login gets redirected to admin area, where different kinds of API calls
like getUserData & updateUserData are called. Requirement is when the user is idle or not in the desk, let's say for 30minutes ttl,
then session data should get deleted from MongoDB database automatically without calling external logout api.

I am not sure whether i can use this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/ .
Is it possible to set TTL and implement based on that?
Can someone suggest me some idea on how can we achieve this from API side?
Any suggestion would be really appreciated

Comment: If you implemented session management in your backend(API) it will automatically Get deleted if you set TTL in the configuration. Refer this https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo

Comment: @Subburaj My doubt is like how from API side how we are able to know whether the user is idle for a specific period of time. As of now only cache and session details are getting deleted, but data in mongodb still persists.

Comment: If you don't want to know explicitly, by default if user doesn't hit any API for 30 mins session management will automatically delete that.

Comment: @Subburaj Yes how can I get lastAccessTime of API call in DB? Do you have some suggestions?

Comment: For LastAccess then you have to do it maintain it manually, for each user the previous accessed time should be maintained in DB

Comment: @Subburaj Like is there any specific method to get lastAccessedTime of each user.  Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Update user last interaction  time with server in DB and run a function in db every 30 mins that will check user last activity time and if it is greater that 30 mins delete the record of the user.